# How do I use multiple <xsl:output> statements in a single xslt file

Tags: html, xml, conditional-statements, xslt-2.0

I would like to use a single XSL to produce multiple output formats (xml and html for now)

I would like to define which output format by means of a stylesheet

So the code I have is as follows:

```
    <xd:doc scope="stylesheet">
        <xd:desc>
            <xd:p><xd:b>Created on:</xd:b> July 1, 2015</xd:p>
            <xd:p><xd:b>Author:</xd:b> me</xd:p>
            <xd:p>A stylesheet to test the application of XYZABC</xd:p>
            <xd:p>takes a single parameter - xslt_output_format</xd:p>
            <xd:p>valid inputs - xml html</xd:p>
        </xd:desc>
    </xd:doc>

    <xsl:output name="xml_out" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml" />
    <xsl:output name="html_out" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes" method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$xslt_output_format = 'xml'">
                <data>
                    <p>This is some test xml output</p>
                </data>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$xslt_output_format = 'html'">
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <title>HTML Test Output</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <p>This is some test html output</p>                        
                    </body>
                </html>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If I pass 'xml' as the parameter I get

This is some test xml output

and if I pass 'html' I get
    
        
            
                HTML Test Output

This is some test html output

That doesn't seem to respect my respect for ISO-8859-1 encoding on the html (which I was just using to test the  was working)

Michael Kay's *XSLT 2.0 and Xpath 2.0* tome is a little vague and definitely short of examples on using multiple  statements (sorry Mike)

So I am just asking am I using it correctly?

Can I achieve what I am aiming for?
TIA
Feargal

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `xsl:output` together with `xsl:result-document` http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#creating-result-trees, so try along the lines of

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$xslt_output_format = 'xml'">
          <xsl:result-document format="xml_out" href="output.xml">
            <data>
                <p>This is some test xml output</p>
            </data>
          </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$xslt_output_format = 'html'">
          <xsl:result-document format="html_out" href="output.html">
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>HTML Test Output</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <p>This is some test html output</p>                        
                </body>
            </html>
          </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

I would probably use templates and modes to distinguish the two different ways of processing but the advice on using `xsl:output` and `xsl:result-document` remains the same.

Comment: I don't want to create output documents. This is being run on an http server and so the output will go straight out into the http-response. No messing with the file-system. So result document doesn't work for me

Comment: You don't have to use the `href` attribute, and where `xsl:result-document` ends up depends on how you call Saxon anyway. My suggestion does not require any output to the file system.

Answer (score 0):

xsl:output by itself doesn't allow you to make any run-time selection of output method.

In 2.0 you can use xsl:output in conjunction with xsl:result-document: the xsl:result-document can select a named xsl:output declaration, or it can override some of its attributes selectively.

Another option (also available in 1.0) is to override xsl:output from the calling API: if you're using JAXP look at Transformer.setOutputProperty().

On the Saxon command line you can set output properties using the syntax !indent=yes on the command line (the "!" needs to be "\!" with some shells).

Comment: Thanks Mike. But reading the docs, there seems to be an implication that the result tree can also affect the output. Is that true with Saxon?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The result tree IS the output.

Comment: I should have said "...there seems to be an implication that the result tree can also affect the output FORMAT."

Comment: If you don't specify an output method, then the default (XML, HTML, or XHTML) depends on the root element of the result tree.